# How to get sqlSession instance in mybatis mapper proxy?

Tags: reflection, proxy-classes, spring-mybatis

I have a [mybatis mapper](https://github.com/zhugw/dyna-modify-mybatis-sql-/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/dynamodifymybatissql/mapper/FooMapper.java)

```
public interface FooMapper {
    @Select("select now()")
    String getTime();
}
```

when debug I got below info

[image]

I want to get sqlSession instance. So I tried using reflection manner to get sqlSession.

```
    Field hField = fooMapper.getClass().getDeclaredField("h");

    MapperProxy mapperProxy = (MapperProxy) hField.get(fooMapper);

    Field sqlSessionField = mapperProxy.getClass().getDeclaredField("sqlSession");
    SqlSession sqlSession = (SqlSession) sqlSessionField.get(mapperProxy);
```

but actually I got below error

```
java.lang.NoSuch FieldException: h
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:2070)
```

So how to get sqlSession instance in fooMapper by reflection manner or other manner(if reflection is impossible)?

Comment: have you found any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
((MapperProxy)((Proxy)fooMapper).h).sqlSession
```

`MapperProxy` from `org.apache.ibatis.binding`

`Proxy` from `Java.lang.reflect`

Comment: this would work at run-time, the compilation fails with this piece of code